# How to load TextureView as a part of view

Tags: android, textureview

I would like to load `TextureView` as a part of my layout. I saw before some examples that it uses `TextureView`  inside `setContentView` function.

```
    ...
    TextureView textureView = new TextureView(this);
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    setContentView(textureView);
```

but I want to load this `textureView` as a part of a xml layout. how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this your can directly add `TextureView` in your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView1"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

or your can dynamically add `TextureView` in your layout like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    LinearLayout rootLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        TextureView textureView = new TextureView(this);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        rootLinearLayout.addView(textureView);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in layout directly with `TextureView` and get it with `findViewById()`.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```